# Get selected text from another app into own C# app

Tags: c#, text, selected, microsoft-ui-automation

I've a C# app that responds correctly to a global hotkey. I want to get the selected text from another app which has the focus if the global hotkey is pressed.

I tested native Win32 Api, then `SendKeys` (**CTRL + C**, Clipboard,...) and now Microsoft UI Automation! The problem is, this only works in Notepad, but not in Internet Explorer or Word or other apps.

I think there must be a better solution than the code I have.  I read that sending `CTRL + C` should work fine, but that only works in Notepad too.

Here's the method I call when the global hotkey is fired:

```
    public String GetSelectedTextFromApp()
    {
        String output = "";
        AutomationElement focused = AutomationElement.FocusedElement;
        object pattern;
        TextPatternRange[] trs;
        if (focused.TryGetCurrentPattern(TextPattern.Pattern, out pattern))
        {
            TextPattern tp = (TextPattern)pattern;
            trs = tp.GetSelection();
            output = trs[0].GetText(-1);
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Check up types of controls you want to copy selection from in *MS Word* and *IE* - it might happen those are *non-standard* controls that are not supported by *UI Automation*.

Answer (score 0):

The control you're trying to automate might not be implementing `TextPattern`. It might only implement `ValuePattern`. Also, it's possible that the control you're focused on isn't the control which actually contains the text, but rather a wrapping control under which you'll find an `AutomationElement` implementing the above mentioned patterns. Another possibility is, like Andrii said, is that the control doesn't support UIA at all (though I find it hard to believe in case of MS Word).

In such cases, it's worth working with UISpy.exe which will help you see the visual tree of the application you're trying to automate. You'll also be able to see the supported `Pattern`s for each `AutomationElement`. You can also call `GetSupportedPatterns()` on every `AutomationElement`, to see which `Pattern`s are currently supported.